# vb.net: comparing two TextFieldParsers

Tags: vb.net, performance, csv, compare, textfieldparser

On my vb.net project, I'm using TextFieldParser inside a timer, to read a csv file every 100 mellisecond. I loop over read records one by one and fill them on a datatable.

looping through all records one by one every 100 ms will be very expensive in terms of performance.

So I defined temp TextFieldParser let's name it TextFieldParser2 and set it to be equal the main TextFieldParser  let's name it TextFieldParser1, at the end of the timer:

TextFieldParser2=TextFieldParser1

then every time the timer event fired I want to check wheather TextFieldParser2 <> TextFieldParser1 to proceed (coz this means the csv file changed), else exit the sub.

I tried:

```
if TextFieldParser2=TextFieldParser1 then
Exit sub
end if
```

and:

```
if TextFieldParser2.equals(TextFieldParser1) then
Exit sub
End if
```

but nothing work.

Comment: Wouldnt if be easier to use a FileSystemWatcher to raise an event when the csv file changes? This way you wont have to spend processing time when it isn't needed.

Comment: I'll search and try it. Thanks you.